# How does Download Later work?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I bought a few games on the eshop today, and selected a few demos. I set them all to Download Later, and then I closed the lid of my 3DS. I figured that would work, as Download Later requires the 3DS to be in sleep mode - but 20 minutes later, all of the games and demos still are at 0% downloaded.

Is there something else I am missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to close the eShop and keep the system on the HOME Menu, but other than that, there really isn't anything else to it - it just needs an Internet connection.

However, note that the eShop can sometimes be *extremely* slow to download from. You may be in for quite a wait; I've once waited about an hour for one of the demos to download.

If all of them continue to stay stuck at 0%, try canceling them and queueing them up again. You might also want to just download them directly from the eShop, without using Sleep Mode; this seems to occasionally work a little better.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that the eShop needed to be closed for it to work. That helped - they downloaded pretty quickly after that.